# Error when I exit from a UIWebVIew respond to selector

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I use a UIWebView to connect my app to the gmail web view... if I close the the viewController.. after a short time I get this error :

```
[MailViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x142c8c00
```

I also try to use the method:

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender{

    [web stopLoading];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

without any success... how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the `UIWebView`'s `delegate` to `nil` in the `dealloc` method of your `MainViewController`.

Thus the webview send some message to its delegate (the `MainViewController`) after it has been deallocated, explaining the crash.

---

From the [`-[UIWebView delegate]` method documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate):

> **Important**: Before releasing an instance of `UIWebView` for which you have set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to `nil`. This can be done, for example, in your dealloc method.